# Non-defining relative clauses

Tags: relative-clauses

Which is grammatically correct to write?

1. They stayed at a grand hotel last fall, which was really costly.
2. Last fall, they stayed at a grand hotel, which was really costly.

Comment: They are both OK, but why do you want the relative clause to be of the supplementary (non-defining) kind?

Comment: BillJ@ Because I had some doubts about the correctness of the relative clause in  the first sentence. Do you think the relative clauses in the two sentences are sematically different?

Comment: They have identical meanings. I was curious about why you put a comma before "which", thus making the relative clauses supplementary (non-defining).

Comment: Because the noun is modified by an adjective, thus we talk a specific hotel that is luxurious and expensive

Comment: The adjective has no bearing on things: You could just as easily say: "We stayed at a (grand) hotel which was really costly" (no comma).

Comment: But l think it is also correct to use a comma, right?

Answer (score -1):

My preferred option is definitely #2, since its not the fall that's costly but the hotel.